# Mockito - check if a method call is made with one of the fields containing a certain string

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, mockito

I am mocking a class called EmailSender which has a method sendEmail() that takes in an argument of class Email. I am trying to verify that my mockEmailSender will call the sendEmail function once with the expected Email class as such: `verify(mockEmailSender, times(1)).sendEmail(expectedEmail)`

```
class Email {
   String title;
   List<String> receipients;
   String body;
}
```

I am initializing the expected Email object like the follow `Email expectedEmail = Email.builder().setRecipients(//example list).setTitle("Test title").setBody(// really long text)`

However, there is a caveat. I also want to add a series of test in which I don't want to verify that the sendEmail is called with the exact `expectedEmail`. I want to have a series of tests in which each test just checks that a certain substring exists in the body field. For example if the Body field is `"Test email body"`, I want one test to verify that `sendEmail()` is called with the expectedEmail argument with body field containing the substring `"Test"` and not specifically that the body field has to be equal to `"Test email body"` while still making sure that the `title` and `receipient` are exactly equal to what I set. How can I do this in Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor) as follows:

```java
ArgumentCaptor<Email> emailCaptor = 
      ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Email.class);
verify(classNameObject, times(1)).sendEmail(emailCaptor.capture());
assertThat(emailCaptor.getValue().getBody())....
```

Keep in mind that `classNameObject` is the instance of the class that contains `sendEmail` method. With this, you can now assert whatever you want in the Email body property.